# Is it possible to add multiple owners to an organization in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops

I can see that it's possible to change the owner of an organization, and I can also add users to the `Project Collection Administrators` group so that they get most administrative rights, but cannot find how to add multiple owners to the organization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have multiple owners for the Azure Devops Organization.

According to [Create and configure organization FAQs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/faq-configure-customize-organization?view=azure-devops#q-how-many-organization-owners-can-i-have):

> **Q**: **How many organization Owners can I have?**
>   **A**: Your organization can have only one owner. Only organization Owners can do certain actions, so make sure you keep your organization Owner updated.